# modify a hash in ruby to make the keys' value to contain nested hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, nested, puppet

I have a hash passed by a user in puppet declaration and for the create_resources to use it, it needs to be added a new nested level with the key remaining to be the key but it's value being set to a nested hash in it with the values from the original value and some string.

like given this

```
      hash = {
            "Field1" => "Value11",
            "Field2" => ["value1","value2"],
      }
```

Then would like to have the new hash after that to be given as this output

```
      hash = {
           "Field1" => { "ensure" => "present",
                          "value"  => "Value11",
                        },
           "Field2" => { "ensure" => "present",
                          "value" => ["value1","value2"],
                       },
            }
```

Tried to do

```
           added = {'ensure' => 'present'}
           hash.zip([added])
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hash.each{|k, v| hash[k] = {"ensure" => "present", "value" => v}}
```